# OracleCommand not ended properly

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, odp.net

I have a query that checks if the user exists in a database. When I check this query through `OracleCommand` it causes exception and says that the `command` is not ended properly.

Here is the query:

```
select count(*) as user_exists
 from users
  where upper(u_name) = upper('name')
  and u_password = DB_PKG_ACCESS.f_encrypt('pass')
  and (expiration_date is null or (expiration_date is not null and trunc(expiration_date) >= trunc(sysdate)));
```

And here is the `command`:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select count(*) as user_exists from users where upper(u_name) = upper('name')"
       +" and u_password = DB_PKG_ACCESS.f_encrypt('pass')"
       +" and(expiration_date is null or(expiration_date is not null and trunc(expiration_date) >= trunc(sysdate)));", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("name", textBox1.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pass", textBox2.Text));
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I'd venture a guess that you should remove the closing semi-colon here `trunc(sysdate)));",`

Comment: It works now. Why don't we write semicolon at the end?

Comment: Harun - OracleCommand is not intended to be used with more than a single statement.  The `;` is designed to separate statements, therefore OracleCommand does not require (or even, accept) it.

Comment: Thank you for explanation :)

Comment: Harun, you are confusing SQL syntax with SQLPlus (scripting) syntax. SQLPlus scripts and their symbols (eg ";")  and keywords can only be used with SQLPlus, SQL Developer, Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio and other tools. Not in APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking out the semicolon from the end of the statement in your OracleCommand like this

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select count(*) as user_exists from users where upper(u_name) = upper('name')"
       +" and u_password = DB_PKG_ACCESS.f_encrypt('pass')"
       +" and(expiration_date is null or(expiration_date is not null and trunc(expiration_date) >= trunc(sysdate)))   ", con);
```

This has been a problem for me before....

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove semicolon in query (Command object is automaticly ended up)

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select count(*) as user_exists from users where upper(u_name) = upper('name')"
   +" and u_password = DB_PKG_ACCESS.f_encrypt('pass')"
   +" and(expiration_date is null or(expiration_date is not null and trunc(expiration_date) >= trunc(sysdate))); <==== Here remove it", con);
```